# Are there hostels in Guernsey?

Tags: budget, accommodation, hostels, channel-islands, guernsey

[Hostel World](http://www.hostelworld.com/) and [HostelBookers](http://www.hostelbookers.com/) have no entries for Guernsey, and a Google search for "hostels in Guernsey" returns only links for hotels. Are there any hostels or shared non-camping accommodation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I contacted the **Guernsey Information Centre**, North Plantation, St Peter Port, GY1 2LQ

Email: info.centre@cultureleisure.gov.gg

There response was simply:

**"Sorry we do not have hostels in Guernsey only normal camp sites"**

Comment: Now that's the way to get a definitive answer :)

Comment: @MarkMayo Thanks, it was also straight to the point as well :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a fairly comprehensive listing of Guernsey accommodation on [Visit Guernsey](http://www.visitguernsey.com/accommodation)

Unfortunately there are indeed no hostels listed. There are a variety of guesthouses, inns and self-catering options.

Or another option might be [Couchsurfing](https://www.couchsurfing.org/n/places/guernsey-united-kingdom), since there are a few hosts there.